# What is wrong with this c++ Code? Break statement

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int num;
    int count;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    if(num>76)
    {
        cout<<"You lose!\n";
        break;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Keep Trucking!\n ";
    count++
}
```

I keep on getting an error message for the break. The compiler is telling me:

```
break statement not within loop or switch
```

I am trying to emulate this code:

```
while (count <= 10)
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    if(num > 76)
    {
        cout<<"You lose!\n";
        break;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Keep Trucking!\n ";
    count++
}
// break jumps to here
```

Why does my attempt fail to compile while this example works?

Comment: `namespace std;` isn't valid C++. `using namespace std;` is likely more what you're looking for. And you don't `break` from an `if`-block. You `break` from loops and switches.

Comment: No that was a transcribing error. Take a look now. I am using http://cpp.sh/ to practice.

Comment: `break` only makes sense inside loops.

Comment: Take a quick read on [break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) :)

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all:

> `break` statement not within loop or switch

There are only two places you can use a `break` statement in C++: within a loop (whether `for`, `while`, or `do/while`) and within a `switch`. Your `break` meets neither of those criteria, so it's invalid.

Note that the code you just posted is structured as:

```
while (count <= 10) {  // <== this loop encloses
    ...
    break;             // <== this break statement
    ...
}
```

whereas your original example has no loop.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx) is the description of break statement from MSDN.

> The break statement ends execution of the nearest enclosing loop or
>   conditional statement in which it appears. Control passes to the
>   statement that follows the end of the statement, if any.

Comment out the break statement as you are not using a while or for statement.

```
if(num>76)
{
    cout<<"You lose!\n";
    //break;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `break`, the OP probably don't know what it does, where and how to use it.

Comment: Can you explain the instructions from the text. I just attached it to the question.

Comment: Added a description of break.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the link. It is there now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want return(1) instead to exit the function. Break is used to 'break' out of a loop. IE if you have a 'for' loop, you can 'break' out of it and stop iterating.

In other words, a return statement will 'break' out of this function and get you the same results you need.

In your code, there isn't a while loop. In the example you've showed, there IS a while loop. If you're attempting to copy that code to learn from , you're missing that line.

Note, that you can return anything. It does not have to be 1. The return keyword is just an alternative to your intended use of break.

Comment: I would refrain returning anything other than success simply because the user lost. The program still ran like it was supposed to.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't demonstrating the return of anything in particular. Just that the keyword return is an alternative to break in this case. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `break` statement inside an `if` loop. You can only use a jump statement like `break` or `continue` within a `for` or `while`. An `if` statement only executes once, whereas a `for` or `while` loop could continue for a while (which is why you'd want to `break` or `continue` from it).

`break` and `continue` will perform the action for the inner-most loop. Having the following code:

```
while (...)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            break; // this IS valid, because it will break from the for loop (only the for loop, not the while loop)
        }
    }
}
```